# query to dispaly from two tables with negation

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, listbox

I have two listboxes,listbox1 and listbox2, and two tables in a DB, table1 and table2.  Both tables contain a column called 'Colour'.  I want to display all 'Colours' from table1 in listbox1 which I‘m able to do.  But in listbox2 I want to display 'Colours' from Table2 but it must not be present  in the Table1 'Colours'.  So how do I write a query for it?

This is what I have been trying and its not working:

```
SELECT Table2.Colour
FROM Table1 CROSS JOIN Table2
WHERE  (Tabel1.Colour! = Table2.colour)
```

Error Message is — `multi-part identifier  Tabel2.Colour could not be found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work with a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT Table2.Colour 
FROM Table2 
   LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Tabel1.Colour = Table2.colour
WHERE Table1.Colour IS NULL
```

You could also use `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS`, I just prefer the `LEFT JOIN` / `IS NULL` syntax.

For example:

```
SELECT Colour 
FROM Table2 
WHERE Colour NOT IN (SELECT Colour FROM Table1)
```

Comment: so how can i make the same query for more tables

Answer (score 0):

If your version of RDBMS implements `EXCEPT` clause,
you can do the following:

```
SELECT Colour FROM Table2
EXCEPT 
SELECT Colour FROM Table1
```

I'm not saying that this is better than JOIN.  Just another option.

Comment: I'm no expert, but it seems that **EXCEPT** is supported: <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055(v=sql.100).aspx> and <http://sqlblog.com/blogs/eric_johnson/archive/2010/03/01/using-sql-server-2008-s-except-and-intersect-statements.aspx>

Comment: hey thanks but how do i do it with more tables.. is it except select colour from Table1,Table2